# Validation of File Upload Control using jquery

Tags: jquery

How to validate asp.net FileUpload control using jquery. 
I need to validate two things, FileUpload should not be empty when user clicks ok button and it should contain only excel and csv files.

please help.

Answer (score 7):

You could validate on extension...

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
   var file = $('input[type=file]').val();       

   if ( ! file) {
       alert('The file is required.');
       event.preventDefault();
       return;
   } 

   if (file.match(/\.(?:csv|xl)$/)) {
       alert('CSV or Excel files only!');
       event.preventDefault();
   }

});
```

...or you could validate on mime type.

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
   var file = $('input[type=file]').prop('files')[0];

   if ( ! file) {
       alert('The file is required.');
       event.preventDefault();
       return;
   } 

   var mime = file.type;

   if (mime != 'text/csv' || mime != 'application/vnd.ms-excel') {
       alert('CSV or Excel files only!');
       event.preventDefault();
   }

});
```

Of course, you need to validate on the server too, this code is just a courtesy to JavaScript enabled users.

Also, choose something better than `alert()`. They are not the most user friendly way of reporting an error.

Comment: I would add a `\.` in there also as a file named `test.zxl` will match

Comment: @alex psycic? On the second one i would testto make sure there were any returned from `$('input[type=file]').prop('files')` first

Comment: hi alex,                                                            <asp:FileUpload ID="fileupload" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnOK" runat="server" Text="OK" Width="60px" 
                        CausesValidation="False"  /> this is the button and fileupload control im using. i used the first code stated above and i replaced [type=file] to [type=fileupload] and then what i need to change for button click. when i click the button nothing is firing

Comment: @chinnu The selectors I used are generic. They will need to be changed to suit your markup.

Comment: @chinnu The selector for the form and the file input.

Comment: var file = $('input[type=fileupload]').val();  y this is showing undefined values always

Comment: @chinnu That is because the `type` attribute is `file`, not `fileupload`. `fileupload` is your `id`. You could use `#fileupload`.

Comment: <asp:Label ID="lblFile" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>             $(document).ready(function () {
 $("#btnOK").click(function () {
 var file = $("#fileupload").val();
                    if (!file) {
                        $("#lblFile").text('Please Upload a File');
                        

                    }
                    else {
                        $("#lblFile").hide();
                    }
                    
                });
            });

Comment: but label text is null on the output page. this is because i have set the label text in design mode as null

Answer (score 2):

You can make the [jQuery validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin to do that for you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form").validate({
        rules: {
            MyFile: {
                required: false,
                accept: "jpg|jpeg|png|gif"
            }
        }
    });

    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var file = $('#MyFile').val();

        if($("#create_form").valid()) {
            if(file != '') {
               // do something
            }
        }
    });
});
```